# Ensure string is in a certain pattern

Tags: php, regex

What is the regex to ensure a string is in below pattern

**string::string** with **|** as the separator if more than one.

For example:

1::String (ok)

1::James is a boy|2::Hello (ok)

1:James is a boy | 2:Hello (not ok - single column)

1:String , 2:Hellos (not ok - separator is a comma)

I tried the following code:

```
$pattern = '/\w::\w|/'; $string = "1::Strings|1::Strings"; preg_match($pattern , $string, $match);
```

Comment: $pattern = '/\w::\w|/';

$string = "1::Strings|1::Strings";

preg_match($pattern , $string, $match); How to enforce the separator if  more than one is the challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex like this

```
^(?:(\w+::\w[^:]+)\|)*(?1)$
```

- `(\w+::\w[^:]+)` the subpattern is the format defined inside the first [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
- `^(?:`...`\|)*` any amount of subpattern inside [non capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) with trailing `|`
- `(?1)` [subpattern](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.recursive.php) is required at least once

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hF5dF6/1)

Comment: modified a little ^(?:(\w+::\w[^:]+)\|\s?)*(?1)$ - to allow space after or before the separator